# AWS HTTP Gateway: Multiple Methods for same Route excluding OPTIONS with Serverless Framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I'm pretty excited about HTTP Gateways due to the drastically reduced pricing in comparison to REST Gateways, but I'm stuck on creating routes that do not completely blow up my `serverless.yml` file.

The documentation for [HTTP Gateway at Serverless](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/http-api/) describes this to define routes:

```
functions:
  params:
    handler: handler.params
    events:
      - httpApi:
          method: GET
          path: /get/for/any/{param}
```

There is a support for `'*'`, but this causes issues with `OPTIONS` cause those will overwrite the created CORS policies (so OPTIONS requests would actually get to the application, which does not make any sense, especially if the route is protected via an authorizer).

Also, it's not possible to define multiple methods.

```
# does not work
method: GET,POST,DELETE

# also not possible
method:
 - GET
 - POST
 - DELETE
```

The only configuration I found is to define all routes separately:

```
events:
  - httpApi:
      path: /someApi/{proxy+}
      method: GET
  - httpApi:
      path: /someApi/{proxy+}
      method: POST
  - httpApi:
      path: /someApi/{proxy+}
      method: DELETE
```

This works fine & the UI is even bundling the routes cause they're on the same prefixed path:

[image]

But with this I have to define all HTTP methods for all my main resources separately including the attached authorizer.

**Is there some way to combine this?**

Comment: I'm also looking for the same thing and I think this is the only way to do it for now. Maybe it's worth requesting this feature on the Serverless GitHub